# How to change color of selected connection in jgrapht or jgraphx?

Tags: java, swing, jgrapht, jgraphx

I'm visualizing a graph in a java swing application using jgrapht/jgraphx.

By default the connections (the arrows that point from one node to an other) between 2 nodes are rendered in light blue. When I select a connection by clicking on it, the color changes from light blue to green.

How can I change this color? I didn't find a way to do this so far. I'm using jgrapht 0.9.1, jgraphx 2.0.0.1, jgraph 5.13.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

And here is the proper way (I think)

```
    mxCellTracker trackColor = new mxCellTracker(myGraphComponent, Color.CYAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT: tested this for JgraphX 3.4.1.3)

This selection color is defined in `mxSwingConstants.java`.

It can be overwritten by:

```
     mxSwingConstants.EDGE_SELECTION_COLOR = new Color(255,0,0,255);
```

But this is not so pretty I would say, and you cannot set it differently for different edges like this. Probably you can change it after some event.

A pretty solution would be if one could add it to an edge style...